# Unable to Resolve module in react-native

Tags: react-native, jsx, native-base

**Problem :** 
Whenever I am trying to import .js or any image file, I get this

> Unable to resolve module Error

I have checked path of files are correct.

**Path :**
[image]

**App.js :**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Container,
  Header,
  Button,
  Icon,
  Item,
  Input,
  Content,
  Footer,
  FooterTab,
  Text,
  Tabs,
  Tab,
  TabHeading,
  Right,
  Left,
  Body,
  Thumbnail,
  StyleProvider
  } from "native-base";
import { Font } from 'expo';

import getTheme from './native-base-theme/components';
import commonColor from './native-base-theme/variables/commonColor';
export default class AnatomyExample extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <StyleProvider style={getTheme(commonColor)}>
      <Container>
        <Header 
           style={{ backgroundColor: "#FFF" }} 
          androidStatusBarColor="#fff">
         <Left>
            <Button>
            <Icon active name="menu" style={{ color: "#5d61cc" }}/>
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Home</Text>
          </Body>
          <Right />
        </Header>
        <Tabs   tabBarBackgroundColor='white'  style={{ elevation: 3 }} >
        <Tab heading={<TabHeading ><Icon name="home" style={{color: "#5d61cc"}}/></TabHeading>} >
           </Tab>

           <Tab  heading={<TabHeading><Icon name="search" style={{color: "#5d61cc"}}/></TabHeading>}>
           </Tab>

          <Tab  heading={<TabHeading><Icon ios='ios-notifications'  android='md-notifications'
           style={{ color: "#5d61cc"}}/></TabHeading>}>
           </Tab>

           <Tab  heading={<TabHeading><Icon name="mail" style={{ color: "#5d61cc"}}/></TabHeading>}>
           </Tab>

        </Tabs>
        <Content padder />

        <Footer style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
        <FooterTab style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
          <Button >
            <Text style={{fontSize: 12, color: "#5d61cc", fontWeight: 'bold'}}>All</Text>
          </Button>
          <Button>
            <Text style={{  fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Mentions</Text>
          </Button>

        </FooterTab>
        <Right>
            <Icon style={{ marginRight: 10, color: "#5d61cc" }} name='settings'></Icon>
        </Right>
      </Footer>

      </Container>
    </StyleProvider>
    );
  }
}

function newFunction() {
  return '';
}
```

**Error:**

> Unable to resolve ./native-base-theme/components" from
>   "./C:\Users\Abc\AwesomeProject\App.js" could not resolve
>   C:\Users\Abc\AwesomeProject\native-base-theme\components' as a
>   file nor as a
>   folder","name":"UnableToResolveError","type":"UnableToResolveError","errors":[{}]},"type":"bundling_error"}"

Comment: You are trying to import a folder `import getTheme from './native-base-theme/components';` , you should import a file inside the folder `components` , or there should be a file called `components.js` inside `native-base-theme`

Comment: @Ashraf Still, It's giving me same error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to import `getTheme` using this way, `./native-base-theme/components`
you have to put index file in your `components` folder.

otherwise, you can import directly from the file where the `getTheme` function is defined.

`import getTheme from './native-base-theme/components/somefile';`

or

`import { getTheme } from './native-base-theme/components/somefile';`

depends on how you define getTheme in that file